# I have problem when add new table in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have problem when add new table in database code first approach.

The error is:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.tbl_Parent_dbo.tbl_Authorizarion_Parent_Id". The conflict occurred in database "adminSection.Models.Context", table "dbo.tbl_Authorizarion", column 'Auth_Id'.

My `Authorizarion` class is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace adminSection.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_Authorizarion")]
    public class Authorizarion
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Auth_Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="you must provied email address")]
        [Display(Name ="Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage ="the Email Address not correct")]

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="you must provied your password ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string User_Type { get; set; }

        public int Par_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Par_Id")]
        public virtual Parent parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my parent class is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace adminSection.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_Parent")]
    public partial class Parent
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Parent_Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Id Att
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must provide parent First Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string Parent_Full_Name{ get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Full Name Att
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must provide parent Email Address")]
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Correct Input")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "at least 10 Char", MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string Parent_Email { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Email Att
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must provide parent phone number")]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public int Parent_Phone { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Phone Number Att
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must provide parent password")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Parent_Password { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Password Att
        /// </summary>

        public string Parent_Location { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End Location Att
        /// </summary>

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must provide parent status")]
        [Display(Name = "Parent status")]
        public string Parent_status { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// End parent status Att
        /// </summary>

        public string Par_User_Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Child> child { get; set; }
        public AdminParent adm_par { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Note> note { get; set; }
        // Note with Parent and note is many to one

        public int Auth_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Auth_Id")]
        public virtual Authorizarion auth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the dbcontext class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Web;

namespace adminSection.Models
{
    public class Context:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Admin> admin { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Child> child { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parent> parent { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AdminParent> adm_par { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Note> note { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Authorizarion> auth { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Student & StudentAddress entity
            modelBuilder.Entity<Authorizarion>()
                        .HasRequired(s => s.parent) 
                        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.auth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a one to one mapping problem. And it's really simple to solve. Using data annotation. And example is given below:

```
    public class Artist {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string StageName { get; set; }
        public virtual ArtistDetails ArtistDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArtistDetails {
       [Key]
       [ForeignKey("Artist")]
       public int ArtistID { get; set; }
       public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
       public string Bio { get; set; }
   }
```

Here, there is a one to one relationship between `Artist` and `ArtistDetail`

Comment: when apply your solution like this  i have this error 
**The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Auth_Id' on type 'adminSection.Models.Admin' is not valid. The navigation property 'Authorizarion' was not found on the dependent type 'adminSection.Models.Admin'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.**